# In pdb how do you reset the list (l) command line count?

Tags: python, pdb

From PDB

```
(Pdb) help l
l(ist) [first [,last]]
  List source code for the current file.
  Without arguments, list 11 lines around the current line
  or continue the previous listing.
  With one argument, list 11 lines starting at that line.
  With two arguments, list the given range;
  if the second argument is less than the first, it is a count.
```

The "continue the previous listing" feature is really nice, but how do you turn it off?

Comment: For those arriving here wondering how to get back to the original starting set, one work-around is `w` to get line number, than for example `l 42` to see 11 lines around line 42.

Comment: and another is: up then down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) it for the behavior you want. For example, here is a full script which adds a "reset_list" or "rl" command to pdb:

```
import pdb

def Pdb_reset_list(self, arg):
    self.lineno = None
    print >>self.stdout, "Reset list position."
pdb.Pdb.do_reset = Pdb_reset_list
pdb.Pdb.do_rl = Pdb_reset_list

a = 1
b = 2

pdb.set_trace()

print a, b
```

One could conceivably monkey patch the standard `list` command to not retain the lineno history.

*edit:* And here is such a patch:

```
import pdb
Pdb = pdb.Pdb

Pdb._do_list = Pdb.do_list
def pdb_list_wrapper(self, arg):
    if arg.strip().lower() in ('r', 'reset', 'c', 'current'):
        self.lineno = None
        arg = ''
    self._do_list(arg)
Pdb.do_list = Pdb.do_l = pdb_list_wrapper

a = 1
b = 2

pdb.set_trace()

print a, b
```

Comment: Thank you I guess this is the way to go for now. Perhaps a patch proposal for python itself?

Answer (score 31):

Late but hopefully still helpful. In pdb, make the following alias (which you can add to your .pdbrc file so it's always available):

```
alias ll u;;d;;l
```

Then whenever you type `ll`, pdb will list from the current position. It works by going up the stack and then down the stack, which resets 'l' to show from the current position. (This won't work if you are at the top of the stack trace.)

Comment: How to add it in the `pdb` config? Now I have to run it every time it breaks on `pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: Put the alias line to a file `.pdbrc`  in CWD or $HOME; On Windows you may also need to set HOME=%HOMEPATH%  manually in the envs because pdb is not using `os.path.expanduser('~')` correctly.

Comment: Best answer :) Thanks.

Comment: I've realised that `ll` is actually an alias that brings you to the end of the file, so I ended up naming it `rl` which stands for "reset list". Hope this helps!

Comment: this is useless nowadays, just do `l.`

Answer (score 26):

Try this.

`(pdb) l .`

Maybe you can always type the dot.

*ps.*
You may consider to use [pudb](https://pypi.org/project/pudb/). This is a nice UI to pdb what [gdbtui](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) is to gdb.

Comment: This should have more upvotes I think...nice answer. I've been annoyed by this for a long time now, and would always type random line numbers till I could figure out where I was. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you use [epdb](https://github.com/sassoftware/epdb) instead of pdb, you can use "l" to go forward like in pdb, but then "l." goes back to the current line number, and "l-" goes backwards through the file.  You can also use until # to continue until a given line.  Epdb offers a bunch of other niceties too.  Need to debug remotely?  Try `serve()` instead of `set_trace()` and then telnet in (port 8080 is the default port).

```
import epdb
epdb.serve()
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a way to turn it off.  It's annoyed me enough that once I went looking in the pdb source to see if there was an undocumented syntax, but I didn't find any.

There really needs to be a syntax that means, "List the lines near the current execution pointer."

Comment: That is both great and horrible news. It's great because now I know this is not a stupid question, horrible because I really like something like this. Since we are going into the feature request category then I'm thinking the best will be to have a reverse operation. Lets call it "rlist" that will be a reverse pager on list. So doing 
(Pdb) l
(Pdb) r
will get you to the same spot.